# keep an gameObject rotated toward the direction its moving to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have the following model. I'm moving it on the screen by changing the transform.position. The problem is I want it to always point with the sphere to the direction it's moving to. How can I keep it always pointing there?

[image]

Comment: Compute the vector it's moving to (or use the velocity vector if you have one), normalize it and get the angle with dot product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
Vector3 previousPosition = transform.position;
transform.position = … // your code
transform.LookAt(transform.position + (transform.position - previousPosition));
```